# ruby to pass arguments to Symbol

Tags: ruby, hash, symbols

Here is a way I found out I can pass pass arguments to Symbol key of a hash.

```
task :test,:server do |t,args|
  puts args.server
  puts end_points[:"#{args.server}"]
end
```

Definition of end_points

```
 end_points = { :dev ==> "http://mysite.com" }
```

This is how I call this rake task:

```
rake test[dev]
```

Is there a cleaner way to pass args.server as key of end_points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Cleaner" is a matter of perspective, but you can write `puts end_points[args.server.to_sym]` if you dislike all that punctuation and just want to make the intent a bit clearer.

Answer (score 2):

To convert a string to a symbol, use the String.to_sym method.That should get you a slightly cleaner implementation.